# How do I make a grouped bar chart with a consistent grid across columns?

Tags: python, altair

I am trying to make a grouped bar chart in Altair where the columns are not so obvious (probably by removing the space between them).

The solution proposed in the issue [here](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/230) relies on several depreciated methods. Additionally, the desired visual grouping described there (which is what I'm looking for) was closed as a vega-lite issue. This has [since been resolved](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/1636).

Is there an updated way to create a cleanly grouped bar chart?

Here's what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import altair as alt

vals = np.concatenate(((np.arange(10) ** 2) / 9, np.arange(10)))
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cat': np.repeat(['a', 'b'], 10),
    'x': np.tile(np.arange(10), 2),
    'y': vals
})

alt.Chart(df).mark_bar(width=20).encode(
    x='cat',
    y='y',
    color='cat',
    column='x'
).configure_view(strokeWidth=0)
```

[image]

Is it possible to keep the horizontal grid lines while also maintaining the space between each group?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine facet spacing with adjusting the scale domain to do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import altair as alt

vals = np.concatenate(((np.arange(10) ** 2) / 9, np.arange(10)))
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cat': np.repeat(['a', 'b'], 10),
    'x': np.tile(np.arange(10), 2),
    'y': vals
})

alt.Chart(df).mark_bar(width=20).encode(
    x=alt.X('cat', scale=alt.Scale(domain=['', 'a', 'b'])),
    y='y',
    color='cat',
).facet(
    'x', spacing=0
).configure_view(
    strokeWidth=0
)
```

[image]

Comment: That works, thanks! I'll have to adjust the labels to be centered, but good enough.